# Cassandra COPY FROM Time and Timestamp columns

Tags: time, cassandra, copy, timestamp, cqlsh

I am trying to COPY FROM a csv file, I have both 1 Timestamp and a time column. 
Trying to test with a couple of rows to begin with:

```
 cqlsh:tests> CREATE TABLE testts (
         ...                    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
         ...                    mdate timestamp,
         ...                    ttime time);
cqlsh:tests> INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
         ... VALUES (1, '2015-10-12', '1055') ;
cqlsh:tests> INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
         ... VALUES (2, '2014-06-25', '920') ;
cqlsh:tests> select * from testts;

 id | mdate                    | ttime
----+--------------------------+--------------------
  1 | 2015-10-12 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000001055
  2 | 2014-06-25 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000000920

(2 rows)
```

**The above works, now I try the import file**

```
cqlsh:tests> COPY testts ( ID,
         ...            mdate,
         ...            ttime)
         ... FROM 'c:\cassandra228\testtime.csv' WITH HEADER = FALSE AND DELIMITER = ',' AND DATETIMEFORMAT='%Y/%m/%d';
Using 3 child processes

Starting copy of tests.testts with columns [id, mdate, ttime].
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 1130 : can't interpret '1130' as a time,  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 1230 : can't interpret '1230' as a time,  given up without retries
Failed to import 1 rows: ParseError - Failed to parse 930 : can't interpret '930' as a time,  given up without retries
Failed to process 3 rows; failed rows written to import_tests_testts.err
Processed: 3 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       1 rows/s
3 rows imported from 1 files in 3.269 seconds (0 skipped).
```

My Timestamp coulmn is formatted YYYY/MM/DD , till I gave this **DATETIMEFORMAT='%Y/%m/%d'** I would get error on the timestamp column but after this that error stopped.

CSV file:
3,2010/02/08,930
4,2015/05/20,1130
5,2016/08/15,1230

How do I fix this.

Thanks much

Comment: show us your schema and some row from the csv

Comment: Here is the whole thing

Comment: which cassandra cql version are you using ?

Comment: It works fine with [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.4 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: **5.01 and 2.2.8**`Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]`

Answer (score 0):

I have check this with same schema and data with `cassandra-2.2.4`'s cqlsh 
All the value are inserted without any Error.

But with `cassandra-2.2.8`'s cqlsh,It's giving me the same Error as yours.
You can fix the with small change in the cqlsh code.

1 . Open the `copyutil.py` file. In my case it was `/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.8/pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.py`
2 .  Find the method convert_time() and changed it to this

```
def convert_time(v, **_):
    try:
        return Time(int(v))
    except ValueError, e:
        pass 
    return Time(v)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, **I tried to try this** but somehow have now gotten into the Python indentation mess. Whatever I do I keep getting 'indentation error, cant even revert back. Using notepad++ I think it is indented correctly but cant bring up cqlsh   File "C:\Cassandra228\apache-cassandra\bin\..\pylib\cqlshlib\copyutil.py", lin
e 1901
    return Time(v)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block  .  I dont know how to fix this - tried commenting, also eclipse/Pylib no help. Can you share a copy of the file, else I simply will have to reinstall Cassandra - totally stuck

Comment: I fixed the compile bug somehow (whew!) notepad++ **show special characters**

Comment: Here is my copyutil file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3G1hA-Owg0SNThLTW11UGRfZlU